# Do we have to use the Lagrange multipliers method?

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Draw a cylindrical container (with a lid), so as to contain $1$ liter of water, using a minimal amount of metal.

Could you give me some hints how we could do that??

Do we have to use the Lagrange multipliers method??

Comment: No, I'm fairly sure you are able to write the surface area solely in terms of either the radius or height of the cylinder, to have an equation with one variable.

Comment: Calculus isnt necessary here, though it certainly can lead to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we have $V=\pi r^2 h=1$ and wish to minimize the surface area $S=2\pi r^2+2\pi rh$.

HINT:

Note that we have $V=\pi r^2 h=1$ as a constraint.

So, eliminate $h$ as $h=1/(\pi r^2)$.

Then, substitute this expression for $h$ into the expression for $S=2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r h$, take the derivative with respect to $r$, set this equal to zero and find the value of $r$ for the minimum of $S$ (i.e, the least amount of metal).

Comment: Could you explain to me the formulas of $V$ and $S$ ??

Comment: They are the volume and surface area (including the top and bottom) of a circular cylinder with radius $r$ and height $h$.  Have you not seen these before?

Comment: Ok... I see... 
$$$$ 
Using Lagrange multipliers method I found the following: 
$$S(r, h)=2 \pi r^2+2 \pi rh \\ \text{ subject to } g(r, h)=\pi r^2 h-1=0$$ We want to find $r$, $h$ and $\lambda$ such that 
$$\nabla S(r,h)=\lambda \nabla g(r,h) \\ g(r,h)=0$$ $$(4 \pi r+2 \pi h, 2 \pi r)=\lambda (2 \pi rh, \pi r^2) \\ \pi r^2 h=1$$ After calculationsI found that $$r=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2\pi}} \ \ , \ \ h=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{2 \pi}}$$ Is this correct??

Comment: At the solutions there is the following answer: The diameter should be equal to the hight $\frac{20}{\sqrt[3]{2\pi}}$ cm. So, have I done something wrong??

Comment: Ok... I see... At the exercise it asks to draw a cylindrical container, does this mean that we have to find the radius and the height??

Comment: So,calculating the radius and the height is meant by drawing the cylindrical container, right??

Comment: Which is the drawing??

Comment: Is the formula $S=2\pi r^2+2\pi r h$ the area of the cylindrical container with the lid or without it?? @Dr.MV

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-) @Dr.MV

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.